# tablesorter child row searching

Tags: tablesorter

I am using tablesorter with child rows. My table has many many child rows per parent row. All child rows have same number of columns as that of parent.

I have filters implemented, with which I can search both parent and child. When I do a search in the filter box for a column, I notice that all filter matches from all columns a child row are also reported. The intend in my application is to report matches for a specific column (same column of filter box) regardless of whether it is a parent or a child.

Has anybody came across this before ?

For example, look at this site

http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-child-rows-filtered.html

If we search for "Colorado" in the "Date" column filter box, one entry will still show up, which has the string "Colorado" in some some unrelated column in the child row.

Comment: Sadly, this ability is [not yet supported](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/574). There are plans to fix it when I have more free time.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The way we overcame was basically to make childrow have its own specific columns and then add external filters only on those columns. Then we had to hide the filters in the header for columns with child column data. Not sure if this has been fixed.

```html
<tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>child column filter 1</td>
            <td class="filter-match">Child column fiter 2</td>
            <td class="filter-match">child column filter 3</td>
        </tr>
```